# No reference images of my daughters face for modeling

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

It may be practical problem of the few beginners, the Problem i am facing is most of the tutorials are using reference images to model face, I also want to model my daughters face but i dont have the reference images like front view, side view, top view, etc also I do not know how to perfectly take photographs of my daughter face to model the same. Can someone shed some light on this problem.. Many thanks

Comment: yes, that solved my problem.. thanks and accepted as duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.8 changed a few things up, like with this instance. On the add object menu (Shift+A) there is an option called 'Image' where you can insert reference pictures and move them around the planes like you would with Blender 2.79's referencing feature. Just make sure you're in orthographic mode when you do this so that your model appears the same size as the photo.